# Error: Qt necesita Xcode 5.0 en MacOS Sierra

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Necesito instalar Qt5 en MacOS Sierra (10.12.6), pero cuando el instalador está apunto de terminar aparece el mensaje:

[image: Qt error al instalar]

Tengo instalada la versión 9.0 de Xcode, pero leí que Qt sólo necesita las herramientas de línea de comandos de éste. Para instalar las herramientas de línea de comandos utilicé:

```
$ xcode-select --install

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

¿Qué necesito para instalar correctamente Qt?

Answer (score 0):

1. Necesitas instalar Xcode versión 5.0 o superior. Puede ser de la [pagina de xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) o buscarlo en la AppStore
2. Una vez instalado ve a Xcode -> Preferences…, click en descargas, click en instalar Command Line Tools.
3. Al terminar la descarga reinicia
4. Intenta instalar de nuevo QtCreator (El instalador de QT utiliza las command line tools para funcionar por eso hay que hacer todo esto.)